# Getting errors nose and tornado were not installed when trying to install TensorFlow from PIP

Tags: tensorflow, pip, tornado, nose

Getting these errors when trying to install TensorFlow
**ERROR: matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.**
**ERROR: matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing tornado nose first using commands:

```
pip install tornado nose --user
```

After installing those, I installed TensorFlow using

```
pip install TensorFlow --user
```

**NOTE:** I used the --user because I got an error when did without adding *--user*

[image: Got Error when tried installing without --user]